# Dropdownlist post in ASP.NET MVC3 and Entity Framework Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have 3 tables:

RateProfile

- RateProfileID
- ProfileName

Rate

- RateID
- RateProfileID
- PanelID
- Other stuff to update

Panel

- PanelID
- PanelName

I have models for each of these. I have an edit page using the RateProfile model. I display the information for RateProfile and also all of the Rates associated with it. This works fine and I can update it fine. However, I also added a dropdown so that I can filter Rates by PanelID. I need it to post back on change so that it can display the filtered rates.

I'm using

```
@Html.DropDownList("PanelID", (SelectList)ViewData["PanelDropDown"], new { onchange = "$('#RateForm').submit()" })
```

for my dropdownlist. Whenever it posts back to my HttpPost Edit method though, it seems to be missing all information about the Rates navigation property. It's weird because I thought it would do exactly what the input/submit button that I have in the form does (which actually passes the entire model back to my HttpPost Edit action and does what I want it to do). The panelID is properly being passed to my HttpPost Edit method and on to the next view, but when I try to query the Model.Rates navigation property is null (only when the post comes from the dropdown. Everything works fine when the post comes from my submit input).

Get Edit:

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, int panelID = 1)
    {

        RateProfile rateprofile = db.RateProfiles.Single(r => r.RateProfileID == id);
        var panels = db.Panels;

        ViewData["PanelDropDown"] = new SelectList(panels, "PanelID", "PanelName", panelID);
        ViewBag.PanelID = panelID;

        return View(rateprofile);
    }
```

HttpPost Edit:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(RateProfile rateprofile, int panelID)
    {
        var panels = db.Panels;
        ViewData["PanelDropDown"] = new SelectList(panels, "PanelID", "PanelName", panelID);
        ViewBag.PanelID = panelID;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(rateprofile).State = EntityState.Modified;

            foreach (Rate dimerate in rateprofile.Rates)
            {
                db.Entry(dimerate).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
            return View(rateprofile);
        }
        return View(rateprofile);
    }
```

View:

```
@model  PDR.Models.RateProfile
@using (Html.BeginForm(null,null,FormMethod.Post, new {id="RateForm"}))
{
    <div>
        @Html.Label("Panel")
        @Html.DropDownList("PanelID", (SelectList)ViewData["PanelDropDown"], new { onchange = "$('#RateForm').submit()" })
    </div>
    @{var rates= Model.Rates.Where(a => a.PanelID == ViewBag.PanelID).OrderBy(a => a.minCount).ToList();}
    @for (int i = 0; i < rates.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => rates[i].RateProfileID)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => rates[i].RateID)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => rates[i].PanelID)

                    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => rates[i].minCount)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => rates[i].minCount)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => rates[i].maxCount)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => rates[i].maxCount)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => rates[i].Amount)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => rates[i].Amount)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
     <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

To summarize my problem, the below query in my view only works when the post comes from the submit button and not when it comes from my dropdownlist.

```
@{var rates= Model.Rates.Where(a => a.PanelID == ViewBag.PanelID).OrderBy(a => a.minCount).ToList();}
```

Comment: Could it be that, when you do your post from the dropdown, some field is making the page not valid, which in your code means that you don't add the rates, hence, when you try to query the rates on your other view they are simply null?

Comment: @TheJonasPersson I wouldn't think so. If I go to the page and just click submit without changing anything, it submits fine and returns the same view, but if I submit via changing the drop down, the model doesn't get passed to my edit action with it's navigation properties intact and the new view that comes up can't query the Rates navigation property and thus all of the editor fields are missing. Either way it should just be doing nothing and returning the current view.

Answer (score 0):

How does it look in the rendered page?  You may have two elements being rendered with the same name/id:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("PanelID", (SelectList)ViewData["PanelDropDown"], new { onchange = "$('#RateForm').submit()"
```

and

```
@Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => rates[i].PanelID)
```

Comment: They are name differently: id="PanelID" name="PanelID" for the dropdown vs id="rates_1__PanelID" name="rates[1].PanelID" for the editor fields

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use Firefox/Firebug to examine the actual request that it is being made.  I can't imagine that the form will post differently if triggered via the submit vs. the button, but I suppose it's possible.

On a larger note, I would make a couple of comments about your design.

1. I would use ViewBag properties for your selections rather than key-based access to ViewData.  This will be much more readable in both your controller and your view.
2. Consider having a separate action that populates the information filtered by the dropdown list.  Render that action in your view based on the PanelID and call that action via AJAX to get the new HTML rather than doing a full form post.
3. Avoid applying your handlers in your markup.  Rather, add an optional Scripts section to your master page and, when needed, add scripts to your page that apply your behaviors through that section.  This allows you to control via the master where view-specific scripts are placed in the document and keeps your behaviors separate from your document structure, a best practice for readability.

Comment: I toook your advice on 1 and 2. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It looks like because I was only looping through a subset of my navigation property (Rates filtered by panelID), the model that was returned from the view only had that subset of navigation properties available to it. After saving the changes, I just redefined my model (called the record from the database again) and it looks good now.

Ie. There were supposed to be 140 records in my navigation property, filtering by panelID == 1 narrowed it down to 28 records. For some reason the entity framework decided that it didn't feel like maintaining the relationship to the other 112 records, so when I changed the dropdown to filter by panelID == 2, the only records available all had panelID == 1 and returned null.